# Where does Postgresql tables DDL get stored?

Tags: postgresql

I know postgresql stores the data in filenodes in base or tablespace but where does postgres use to store ddl for tables?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalogs.html

Comment: The actual DDL - the SQL code you entered - is not stored anywhere.

Comment: usng the language in original post, data definition is stored in "in filenodes in base" as well, but if you need the pretty DDL you need to `pg_dump -s` to format all for you